# Transaction identifier filed in transaction receipt is different from another user

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am doing one application.In that i am using InAppPurchase concept.In that i am implementing auto renewal subscription.Whenever i subscribe for product,I am sending the receipt to apple server from my server.In that i am getting the response from apple.That response contain different fields.In that fields,i want to know about transactionIdentier.Is this fileds is different from every payment.Means whenever i subscribe first time whatever i get is this same as whatever i get at the time of renewal.And if another user subscribe for same item then that person also get the same transactionIdentifier or different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is that all users and all transactions get a unique transactionIdentifier (which unless I've misread is a string of numbers). If you want the transactionIdentifier from when the user first subscribed, I believe you can get that from `transaction.originalTransaction` during `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` and I believe that is the same as looking for the `original_transaction_id` field on your server.